# Accessing external C++ DLL

Tags: java, c++, dll, external

First I did search this forum for an answer. From the search I tried and still feel struck and hence this question. So please bear with me.
There is an external C++ DLL from the opensource that I want to access in my java application
The open source is http://phtranslator.sourceforge.net/ - it provides DLL to transliterate english strings into indic unicode strings.

here is my code:
public class IndicTranslator {

```
public interface PhTranslator extends Library {
    PhTranslator INSTANCE = (PhTranslator)
        Native.loadLibrary("dist/lib/PhTranslateLib.dll", PhTranslator.class);
    Pointer GetTamilTranslator();
    int Translate(Pointer translator, String szEnglish, WString szLang, int szLen);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PhTranslator indicTranslator = PhTranslator.INSTANCE;
    WString szLang = null;
    int szLen = 128;
    Pointer tamilTranslator = indicTranslator.GetTamilTranslator();
    indicTranslator.Translate(tamilTranslator, "vaNakkam", szLang, szLen);
    System.out.println(szLang+" Length="+szLen);
}
```

}

The above code compiles but returns prints null. Any help what I am doing wrong. I expected it displays "Indic Characters"

Comment: Of course it prints `null` as you defined `szLang` with null and never assign a value to it. This is not a Cpp pointer! I am not familiar with the API, but you might have to properly initialize `WString`...

Comment: I am sorry. szLang was supposed to be a returned by the function "Translate" of the external DLL. I assigned it an initial value - because eclipse complained it did not have initial value.

Comment: I am sorry. szLang was supposed to be a returned by the function "Translate" of the external DLL. I assigned it an initial value - because eclipse complained it did not have initial value.  The signature of the function in the External DLL is as follows:
    PHTRANSLATELIB_API int Translate(void* Translator, const char* szInput,wchar_t* szOutput, const int nLen);
Hope that helps. I am sure something is wrong in the way I am trying to access to the external function.

Comment: I changed WString to char[] = new char[128]
I get some output - but not I expected something in indic...